# Собирать проект при помощи webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babel

Привет. Сейчас у меня установлен npm + Babel, у которого сборка происходит при помощи `npm run watch`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d dist --presets es2015",
  "watch": "babel src -d dist --presets es2015 -w"
}
```

Но у меня не получается import файлов в клиентский JavaScript. Для этого я хочу использовать WebPack. Как настроить WebPack так, чтобы он собирал файлы при помощи Babel?

Comment: Очень хороший скринкаст, на все случаи жизни. Про бабель там тоже рассказывается.
https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/webpack

Answer (score 0):

Вот **webpack.config.js**

```
// Для использования нужен Node.JS
// Поставьте webpack:
//   npm i -g webpack
// Поставьте babel-loader:
//   npm i babel-loader
// Запустите его в директории с файлами:
//   webpack

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./build.js"
    },

    watch: true, // просмотр включен

    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 100 //время тайм аута просмотра изменений
    },
    plugins: [ ],
    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

**если что не понятно распишу подробнее**